# How do I get a redirect URL back to my Chrome extension popup?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to authenticate with the Hubspot API. I am using `chrome.identity.getRedirectURL` to get a redirect URL for the API. What do I pass in so that after the API is done authenticating, it opens my popup again? Do I need to look at this from another perspective? The ultimate end goal is to get the API response back to my popup.

To clarify, the Chrome popup is the window that shows up when you click on the Chrome extension icon next to the address bar.

My current code is below:

```
        let redirectURL = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL("index.html");

        let clientID = config.clientID;
        let clientSecret = config.clientSecret;

        // create object to make the authentication request with
        let details =  {
            url: "https://app.hubspot.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=" + clientID + "&scope=contacts&redirect_uri=" + redirectURL,
            interactive: true
        };

        // make authentication request
        chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(details, (response) => {
            alert(response);
        })
```

`index.html` is my popup page; I don't know if this part is correct or not.

EDIT: added clarification on the `index.html` line of code.